# Javascript - simple counting

Tags: javascript, forms, increment

This is my first post and second day with Javascript ;). I try to create a simple form, which:

1. Allows user put any letter / letters in an input field.
2. Than I want to send it to my script and:
    a) check if anything was given in a form
    b) if the user put any sign i want to put it in an array and count up the number of tries
    c) if the number of tries reach 10 I want to to stop the script

My script doesn't remeber the number of tries. Moreover, it saves the data in an array but after the script is done it erases everything (I put some console.log() in the script, to see if it does anything). It looks like my variable count doesn't remember the number of tries :(.

How can I fix it ? - but in a simple way of coding :) (I don't want to do a lot of changes in my code)

```
<script type= "text/javascript"> 

var given_letters = []; // create an empty array

function givenLetter() {
    var count = 0;
    var max_count = 10;
    var letter =  document.getElementById('letter').value;

    while (count < max_count) { 
        if (letter ===  "") {
            alert("No letter given");           
            return false;
        } else {            
            count++;  
            given_letters.unshift(letter);
            console.log(letter); // returns letter
            console.log(given_letters); // returns array with 1 element
            console.log(count); // returns "1"
            alert("OK");
            return true;
        }
    }
    while (count === max_count) {
        alert("Sorry. You exceeded the limit of tries.");
        return false;
    }
}                    
</script>


// in BODY section
    <div>
        <form><p>Put your letter here: <input type="text" id="letter"  size="5" required><button onclick="givenLetter();">Send</button></p></form>
    </div>
```

Comment: `while (count === max_count)` ... you'll get a bad surprise when this condition is met.

Comment: Stop using the tutorial/page you are using for learning. It's from 2000. Don't use inline js (`onclick="givenLetter();`), attach an eventListener instead.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it ;) - I suppose I should change it to IF. But my concern now is the "else {" part :(

Comment: OK @baao I'll check it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
Since the button i within the form tag the default behavior of button is submit. so the form will be submitted and reload the page. So to prevent that behavior we use `event.preventDefault();` and make count as a global variable.

```js
var given_letters = []; // create an empty array
var count = 0;
 

function givenLetter() {
    event.preventDefault(); //to prevent reloading the page.
    var max_count = 10;
    var letter =  document.getElementById('letter').value;

    while (count < max_count) { 
        if (letter ===  "") {
            alert("No letter given");           
            return false;
        }
        else {            
            count++;  
            given_letters.unshift(letter);
            console.log(letter); // returns letter
            console.log(given_letters); // returns array with 1 element
            console.log(count); // returns "1"
            alert("OK");
            return true;
        }
    }
    while (count === max_count) {
        alert("Sorry. You exceeded the limit of tries.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
            <form>
            <p>Put your letter here: <input type="text" id="letter"  size="5" required>
            <button onclick="givenLetter();">Send</button></p></form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is this is your expected output?

Comment: Thank you ;). This is exactly what I needed :D. Now - step by step -  I'll check yours answer and @David Lee code, to understand why it works ;). Thank you all for your help !

Comment: I did press an arrow up, but it looks like my "reputation" is too low

Comment: Ohh I didn't notice that ;). Thanks for a tip

Answer (score 2):

You can use `given_letters.length` instead of `count`, less code and its the same value, you need to use `e.preventDefault();` so the form doesnt submit the form yet, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m6pvq12v/7/) its a working example, for `e.preventDefault();` to work you need to send the event in the button, like this:

```
    <div>
        <form>    
         <p>Put your letter here: <input type="text" id="letter" size="5" required>
         <button onclick="givenLetter(event);">Send</button></p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

the JS updated:

```
var given_letters = []; // create an empty array
function givenLetter(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var max_count = 10;
    var letter =  document.getElementById('letter').value;

    while (given_letters.length <= max_count) {
        if (letter ===  "") {
            alert("No letter given");           
            return false;
        }
        else {            
            given_letters.unshift(letter);
            console.log(letter); // returns letter
            console.log(given_letters); // returns array with 1 element
            console.log(given_letters.length);//here is your count already
            alert("OK");
            return true;
        }
    }
    while (given_letters.length === max_count) {
        alert("Sorry. You exceeded the limit of tries.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of a button in a form is to submit the form... and reload the page (quite stupid, IMO). This is why your script doesn't seem to remember anything. But there's a way to prevent that.
Also, write `var count = 0;` *outside* the function, otherwise it's being set to 0 every time the function is called.

```
var count = 0;

function givenLetter(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ....
```

Comment: He also sets count to 0 on every click of the button

Comment: Yes, that as well. At first glance, I thought it was counting the letters. I have updated my answer, thanks

Comment: @baao at first though the same but that its not the error

Comment: @baao - I'he noticed that it looks like my variable "count" is always "0". I don't know how to stor it in var count. I use count++ but it doesn't store the data. It erases the count value after the script is reloaded

Comment: Yes, hence my answer. Try it.

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy Thille. I'll read  about this "event.preventDefault()"